# Is it necessary to detach a SQLite database after attaching it?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-drive-api

In order to sync the data between devices, I retrieve a backup database on the device and then request this backup database to update the one currently used by my application.

I use this code to attach the backup database:

```
try {
    db.execSQL("attach database ? as " + DATABASE_BACKUP_NAME, new String[]{dbFile.getPath()});
} catch(SQLiteException e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleDrive: Database already in use, continue...");
}
```

I use the try catch to go on when the backup database is already attached.

Is it a good way or is it better to detach and attach the database again every time?

Why would it be useful to detach the database?

**Note**: This is the only information from the SQLite documentation:

> This statement detaches an additional database connection previously attached using the ATTACH statement. When not in shared cache mode, it is possible to have the same database file attached multiple times using different names, and detaching one connection to a file will leave the others intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only keep that backup db attached for as long as I need it and then detach it. Think of it like this: you would keep a file open if you don't need it anymore? Treat the attached database as a resource. Allocate the resource  when you need it, deallocate when you don't.

Comment: I guess you're right, I was just a bit concerned about the performance but I don't think this will make a big difference.